# Removing/adding link class onclick

Tags: jquery, class

I researched quite a bit on onClick changes for links but couldn't quite figure out the solution I need. I have a side bar menu that contains three links. I have a default "active" class added to the content I want to appear as default. However when I click another link in the sidebar, I want the previous link's "active" class to be removed, replaced with "inactive", then apply "active" to the new link. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="1" class="active">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2" class="inactive">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="3" class="inactive">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a.active {
    background-color:#ccd9ff;
    border-radius:15px 15px;
}

a.inactive {
    border:0;
    background:0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.inactive').click(function(){
        $('a.inactive').removeClass('inactive');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

I read this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751329/change-css-link-property-onclick-with-javascript-jquery) which helped me figure out how to addClass onclick (above), however I wasn't able to then remove the 'active' class of the inactive links. Can someone help me out?

Comment: @Mario: The CSS `:active` has different meaning from what OP is trying to achieve. It doesn't remember the last element clicked, but instead references the element that is currently being clicked. When the click event is done, `:active` no longer matches. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/TB2rn/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event delegation would be nice here. You can use the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method to only trigger the handler on descendants of `#sidebar` that have the `inactive` class.

Then use the [`toggleClass()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method to toggle the `active` and `inactive` classes.

```
$(function(){
    var sidebar = $('#sidebar');  // cache sidebar to a variable for performance

    sidebar.delegate('a.inactive','click',function(){
        sidebar.find('.active').toggleClass('active inactive');
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    });
});
```

**You can test the code here:** http://jsfiddle.net/dstpt/

Answer (score 1):

If I"m understanding, you want this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.inactive').click(function(){
        $("a.active").removeClass("active")
                     .addClass("inactive");

        $(this).removeClass('inactive')
               .addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to only remove the class from the current `a`.

```
$(function(){
    $('a.inactive').click(function(){
        $('a').addClass('inactive');
        $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, partially. When I click an `.inactive` link, it changes the class and everything works. However, when I go back to the original link on which I had `.active` as default, it's background doesn't go to `.active`. The content the link is associated with appears, but the `.active` link appears on a different "tab". Thoughts?

Comment: @tvalent2, try the edited version. You may want to limit the selector to `#sidebar a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here $(document).ready(function () {
$('.show-sidebar').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#main').toggleClass('sidebar-show');
    setTimeout(MessagesMenuWidth, 250);
});
var ajax_url = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
if (ajax_url.length < 1) {
    ajax_url = 'ajax/dashboard.html';
}
LoadAjaxContent(ajax_url);
$('.main-menu').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    var parents = $(this).parents('li');
    var li = $(this).closest('li.dropdown');
    var another_items = $('.main-menu li').not(parents);
    another_items.find('a').removeClass('active');
    another_items.find('a').removeClass('active-parent');
    if ($(this).hasClass('dropdown-toggle') || $(this).closest('li').find('ul').length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('active-parent');
        var current = $(this).next();
        if (current.is(':visible')) {
            li.find("ul.dropdown-menu").slideUp('fast');
            li.find("ul.dropdown-menu a").removeClass('active')
        }
        else {
            another_items.find("ul.dropdown-menu").slideUp('fast');
            current.slideDown('fast');
        }
    }
    else {
        if (li.find('a.dropdown-toggle').hasClass('active-parent')) {
            var pre = $(this).closest('ul.dropdown-menu');
            pre.find("li.dropdown").not($(this).closest('li')).find('ul.dropdown-menu').slideUp('fast');
        }
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') == false) {
        $(this).parents("ul.dropdown-menu").find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('ajax-link')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('add-full')) {
            $('#content').addClass('full-content');
        }
        else {
            $('#content').removeClass('full-content');
        }
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location.hash = url;
        LoadAjaxContent(url);
    }
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
var height = window.innerHeight - 49;
$('#main').css('min-height', height)
    .on('click', '.expand-link', function (e) {
        var body = $('body');
        e.preventDefault();
        var box = $(this).closest('div.box');
        var button = $(this).find('i');
        button.toggleClass('fa-expand').toggleClass('fa-compress');
        box.toggleClass('expanded');
        body.toggleClass('body-expanded');
        var timeout = 0;
        if (body.hasClass('body-expanded')) {
            timeout = 100;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            box.toggleClass('expanded-padding');
        }, timeout);
        setTimeout(function () {
            box.resize();
            box.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
        }, timeout + 50);
    })
    .on('click', '.collapse-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var box = $(this).closest('div.box');
        var button = $(this).find('i');
        var content = box.find('div.box-content');
        content.slideToggle('fast');
        button.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
        setTimeout(function () {
            box.resize();
            box.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
        }, 50);
    })
    .on('click', '.close-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var content = $(this).closest('div.box');
        content.remove();
    });
$('#locked-screen').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').addClass('body-screensaver');
    $('#screensaver').addClass("show");
    ScreenSaver();
});
$('body').on('click', 'a.close-link', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    CloseModalBox();
});
$('#top-panel').on('click','a', function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('ajax-link')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('add-full')) {
            $('#content').addClass('full-content');
        }
        else {
            $('#content').removeClass('full-content');
        }
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location.hash = url;
        LoadAjaxContent(url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.inactive').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('inactive'); //remove the class *only* from this one
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't remove `.active` on the other links that have been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#sidebar').click(function(){
       $("a.active").removeClass("active")
           .addClass("inactive");
       $(this).removeClass('inactive')
           .addClass('active');
    });
});
```