# Javascript code to change the div style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a `div`:

```
 <DIV CLASS= "KJX" > 
     // DIV CONTENT
 </DIV>
```

after clicking on the div, I want to change the div style to this:

```
   <style> 
       background-color: red;
       font-type: oswald;
   </style>
```

I want the change to stay on the div after clicking, not just during the clicking. Is there script for that?

Comment: can you use jQuery? :)

Comment: mmm  i will try , hit me

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751329/change-css-link-property-onclick-with-javascript-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096739/jquery-change-style-of-a-div-on-click

Comment: you'll want to use `font-family`, not font-type. Also, this question already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be:

```
$(function() {
              $('.home').click(function() {
                    $(this).css({'background-color', 'red'});
              });
        }):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
              $('.KJX').click(function() {
                    $(this).css({ 'background-color ': 'red'
                                 'font-type' :' oswald'});
              });
        });
```

HOpe this will work

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery solution would be:

```
$('.kjx').click(function(){
   $(this).css({'background-color' : 'red', 'font-type' : 'oswald'});
});
```

Comment: sir ,  i know these codes , i wanna the change to stay on the div , this effect will disappear after the clicking

Comment: I think it wont, just try it :)